# Catching which cell changed in editable datagrid

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio, wpf-controls

I have an editable DataGrid in a VB WPF application.  The DataGrid itself has its SourceUpdated property set to my event handler.  2 of the columns in the grid are editable and have their NotifyOnSourceUpdated flag in the Binding set to True.  The event is firing properly, but I can't seem to figure out the best way to determine what has changed.  The 2 columns depend on each other in that one of them is an item quantity and the other is a case quantity.  If the user changes one of them I want to re-compute the other value and update the grid as well as the binding source.  I'm sure there are a number of ways to handle this, but I'm curious what is the best way.  I could listen for change event on the datagrid, see what changed, set some variables, and then use those in the SourceUpdated event, but that doesn't seem elegant.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Asking for the "best" way leads to subjective answers and is generally discouraged in S.O. But I am confused by the wording of your question: are you looking for a way to determine which cell has triggered the change event?

Comment: Understood on the "best" concern...my bad.  But yes, basically, that's what I was asking, but I think AngelWPF's answer will do what I need.  My datagrid is bound to an ObservableCollection, but I'm still new to this stuff and didn't think about the PropertyChanged event.  I will try that out and see how it goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to come out of the world of event handlers! WPF discourages taking the old WinForms approach of doing everything in event handlers.

**MVVM way ....**

You must leverage the power of your model class in the MVVM way. The bound collection to your datagrid must be a collection of some items... e.g. if you datagrid is showing list of `Employees` then your collection must be some `IEnumerable<Employee>` ... So the `Employee` class can help you here.

Assume that your datagrid shows `Gender` and `Saluation` as two interrelated editable columns. So your `Employee` class should have following things in it...

```
1. `Employee` class must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.
2. `Gender` and `Salutation` properties must raise the `PropertyChanged` event from their property setters.
3. In the setter of `Gender` \ `Salutation` we must write the logic of changing the other field.
```

E.g.

```
            private string _gender;
    public string Gender
    {
        get
        {
            return _gender;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_gender != value)
            {
                _gender = value;

                if (_gender == "Male")
                {
                    Salutation = "Mr";
                }
                else if (_gender == "Female"
                     && (Salutation == "Mr" || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Salutation)))
                {
                    Salutation = "Ms";
                }
                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_gender))
                {
                    Salutation = string.Empty;
                }

                OnPropertyChanged("Gender");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _salutation;
    public string Salutation
    {
        get
        {
            return _salutation;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_salutation != value)
            {
                _salutation = value;

                if (_salutation == "Mrs" || _salutation == "Ms")
                {
                    Gender = "Female";
                }
                else if (_salutation == "Mr")
                {
                    Gender = "Male";
                }
                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_salutation))
                {
                    Gender = string.Empty;
                }

                OnPropertyChanged("Salutation");
            }
        }
    }
```

Where `OnPropertyChanged()` is ...

```
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

This way your GUI will automatically perform the conversion of the related fields.

**The ValueConverter way ...**

If your fields are not to be stored into the model but are only for display purpose then you can use `ValueConverter`....

```
public class GenderToSalutationConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert
        (object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var _gender = (string) value;
        if (_gender == "Male")
        {
            return "Mr";
        }
        else if (_gender == "Female")
        {
            return "Ms";
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack
           (object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var _salutation = (string)value;
        if (_salutation == "Mrs" || _salutation == "Ms")
        {
            return "Female";
        }
        else if (_salutation == "Mr")
        {
            return "Male";
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

in **XAML**

```
   <UserControl.Resources>
       <local:GenderToSalutationConverter x:Key="GenderToSalutationConverter"/>
   </UserControl.Resources>
   <tk:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">
        <tk:DataGrid.Columns>
             <tk:DataGridTextColumn
                        Header="Sex"
                        Binding="{Binding Gender,
                           Converter={StaticResource GenderToSalutationConverter}}">
            </tk:DataGridTextColumn>
            <tk:DataGridTextColumn
                        Header="Title"
                        Binding="{Binding Salutation}">
            </tk:DataGridTextColumn>
        </tk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </tk:DataGrid>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I had *most* of this in place already (i.e., my collection was an ObservableCollection and the objects in the collection did implement INotifyPropertyChanged, etc).  I was missing the piece about raising the PropertyChanged event.  It's working great now.  Thanks!!